# Как заблокировать URL-адрес или файл .js?

Tags: javascript

У меня установлено расшерение для браузера Greasemonkey. Расширение позволяет добовлять свои скрипты на любой сайт. Пытаюсь заблокировать загрузку скрипта, но ничего не получается. Нашёл несколько ппримеров кода по этому вопросу, но почему-то они у меня не работают. Пробовал и на других подобных расширениях, но результат нулевой. Может кто знает как всё же заблокировать загрузку фала js?

```
<script>
    function blockScript(origin) {
        const scripts = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT"));
        if (scripts.length > 0) {
            scripts.forEach((script) => {
                if (script.src.includes(origin)) {
                    document.head.removeChild(script);
                }
            })
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
        for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
            const addedNodes = Array.from(mutation.addedNodes);
            if (addedNodes && addedNodes.some(n => n.nodeName === 'SCRIPT')) {
                blockScript('code.jquery.com');
            }
            observer.disconnect();
        }
    });
    observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous" ></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('I am undefined');
    })
</script>


// ==UserScript==
// @name        New script 
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       *flarum.org*
// @include     *flarum.org*
// @grant       none
// @version     1.0
// @run-at      document-start
// @author      -
// @description 12/26/2020, 9:57:34 AM
// ==/UserScript==

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(({ addedNodes }) => {
    addedNodes.forEach((addedNode) => {
      if (addedNode.nodeType === 1 && addedNode.matches('script') && addedNode.src === 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js') {
        addedNode.remove();
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
  });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: А чего же вы ожидали? У вас скрипт ждёт создания новых нод в документе (точнее мутаций DOM-а), а вы также должны проверять уже существующие ноды прямо с запуска скрипта.

Comment: @ΝNL993, как проверять уже существующие ноды прямо с запуска скрипта? Буду рад любой помощи)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => script.remove())` - это вставляете в начало скрипта (то-есть после `// ==/UserScript==`).

Comment: ΝNL993, вроде начало что-то работать, но не так как надо) Скрипт мне блокирует все файлы js или почти все, но не блокирует тот, который указываю я. И есть ещё нюанс, блокировка происходит только после того, как я обновляю страницу.)

Comment: *Скрипт мне блокирует все файлы js или почти все, но не блокирует тот, который указываю я.* -- А у вас на клавиатуре только `Ctrl`, `C` и `V`, или что? Почему вы не можете дополнить код? *И есть ещё нюанс, блокировка происходит только после того, как я обновляю страницу.)* -- вам пришлось перезагрузить страницу только раз, или это требуется делать постоянно?

Comment: @ΝNL993  строчку я добавили получилость: document.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => script.remove())
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(({ addedNodes }) => {
    addedNodes.forEach((addedNode) => {
      if (addedNode.nodeType === 1 && addedNode.matches('script') && addedNode.src === 'https://st.fotocdn.net/_app/dist/services/hb/v82/prod/service_hb.umd.min.active.js') {
        addedNode.remove();
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
  });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });

Comment: @ΝNL993, при переходе на страницу блокировка не происходит., а обновляешь страницу блокируется. Переходишь на другую траницу и снова нужно обновить, чтоб заблокировалось.

Comment: У вас сайт случаем не SPA?

Comment: ΝNL993, так это же не мой сайт. Я же написал, что скрипт я добавляю через расшерения для браузера 
Greasemonkey, пробую ещё на расширении User JavaScript and CSS

Comment: Без разницы, сайт сам по себе SPA или нет?

Comment: @ΝNL993, как узнать SPA не SPA? Ещё бы хорошо знать что такое SPA)

Comment: Читайте. Я же вам сейчас не буду тут статью про SPA выкладывать.

Comment: Всё, я не намерен продолжать беседу. Вы не проявляете желание учится и доделывать самостоятельно (это также процесс обучения), соответственно я не проявляю желание помогать вам. Под конец, подскажу вам что вам нужно обратить внимание на метод `disconnect` у наблюдателя.

Comment: ΝNL993, спасибо, что уделили время.